# Counting raw_input numbers

Tags: python, counting, raw-input

python 2.7: Count how many numbers are entered by the user.
I can't figure out how to count the raw_input... here's what I have so far:

```
while True:
    datum = raw_input('enter a number: ')  
    if datum == 'done': break                  

count = 0                                    
for line in datum:                           
    if datum == int(datum):
         count = count + 1 

print 'count', count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try` and `except`

`count=0` should be before the while

try:

```
count = 0 

while True:
    datum = raw_input('enter a number: ')  
    if datum == 'done': break                  

    try:
        int(datum)
        count += 1
    except ValueError:
        pass

print 'count', count
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I then add up(sum) all the numbers entered without using sum()?

Comment: @NamedN If you want to get the sum then add before the while, total = 0, and change int(datum) with total += int(datum)

Comment: This dosen't work you'll get stuck in the while loop except you enter done

Answer (score 0):

```
datum = []
total = 0
count = 0
while True:
    data = raw_input('enter a number: ')  
    if data == 'done': break                  
    datum.append(data)
for i in datum:
    try:
        total = total + int(i) 
        count += 1
    except:
        pass
print 'count', count, ' total',total
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
while True:
     dat_num = raw_input('enter a number: ')
     if dat_num == 'done':break
     else:
          dat_num = int(dat_num)
          count += dat_num
     print 'count', count
```